# shimx64.efi missing on ubuntu live usb

Tags: boot, uefi

Every time I create my ubuntu live USB I do NOT see shimx64.efi available. I only see grubx64.efi . How do I fix this?

I have created USBs using unetbootin, rufus, and startup disk creator on ubuntu, and none of them work as I still don't see shimx64.efi. And I used a GPT partition table with UEFI like everyone suggested. It still doesn't work.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The live media uses the default device bootloader, in /EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI.  That file is a copy of shimx64.efi.  grubx64.efi needs to be present in the same directory (and is).